# How to run cypher queries programmatically (using php) while working with graphenedb?

Tags: php, neo4j, export, graphaware, graphenedb

I am able to create nodes and edges (using GraphAware framework) on graphenedb for my application. I would now like to visualize the generated network on my app as an SVG image. 
Neo4j browser allows us to export the SVG and save it on the PC. But instead of going on the browser to download the image and then writing code to import the image on the webpage, I want to programmatically perform "MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN n,r,m", export as SVG and save it to my server in PHP. Any suggestions on how to do this?